# What is the limit of $nf(x+n)$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$? Here $f(x)$ is prob. density function.

Tags: probability-theory, improper-integrals

I tried the cases when $f(x)$ are the densities of normal and student t distribution. In both cases, the limit is $0$. I guess this conclusion might hold in general. I tried the following.

Let $a_n(x)=nf(x+n)$. We are interested in $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n(x)$ if exists. For each $n$, we have $f(x+n)=a_n(x)/n$. We have
$$
1=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x+n)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{a_n(x)}{n}\,\mathrm{d}x.
$$
We can conclude at least that $a_n(x)<O(n)$, otherwise $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{a_n(x)}{n}\,\mathrm{d}x$ is infinite.

My real target is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty nf(x+n)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$. Is this limit finite? Any thoughts about how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: Anything can happen, even $f(n)\to\infty$. Think of a PDF with spikes.

Comment: You can't really have a spike at $\infty$ though, wouldn't be well defined.

Comment: $f(x+n)>\frac1n$ can happen only on a set of measure zero. Then again, $x+\mathbb Z$ might be this set.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I don't understand. Could you give more explanation?

Comment: $f$ can have removable singularity at arbitrary large point, as an modification to the function in a set of measure 0 have no effect whatsoever on the distribution. This would cause the limit to be not existing. You might need to impose some stronger condition on $f$.

Comment: @Silynn Sorry? What is not "well defined" here?

Comment: The two last lines of the current version of the question are unrelated to the title and to the rest of the post.

Comment: Why do you fail to react to the complete answer I posted?

Answer (score 1):

> My real target is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty nf(x+n)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$. Is this limit finite?

Not always, and the integral itself need not be finite. For a counterexample, consider the PDF
$$
f=\sum_{n\geqslant1}2^n\,\mathbf 1_{(n,n+1/4^n)},
$$
then, for every $t$,
$$
\int_\mathbb Rf(x)f(x+t)\mathrm dx=\sum_{k,\ell}2^{k+\ell}\mathrm{Leb}((k,k+1/4^k)\cap(\ell-t,\ell+1/4^\ell-t)),
$$
thus, for every nonnegative integer $n$, keeping only the indices $(k,\ell)$ such that $\ell=k+n$, one gets
$$
\int_\mathbb Rf(x)f(x+n)\mathrm dx=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{2k+n}\mathrm{Leb}((k,k+1/4^k))=+\infty.
$$
For $C^\infty$ counterexamples, consider convolutions with normal densities of small variances.